# how to load asyctask if new image is arrived in device ?

Tags: android

i have designed custom gallery but problem is that every time when i open gallery asyctask is call and all image getting load again. i want to load asyctask if new images arrived into device otherwise directly gallery will be shown without load

i have no more idea that how to do this kind of programming stuff so if there is anyway to do this kind of stuff then please suggest me

is there any way to do this ... ??

```
private class AsyncTaskForListview extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String responce;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            getAllGalleryFolderName(); // process for get image 
            return responce;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            lvShowAllImageFolder.setAdapter(effectImageAdapter); // set adapeter in listview 
            effectImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog
                    .show(DisplayGalleryActivity.this,
                            getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.progress_dialog_heading),
                            getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.progress_waiting_message));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileObserver class to monitor a file or fold. It will notify if a change by any process in the device occurs. More details [here](http://www.roman10.net/2011/08/06/android-fileobserverthe-underlying-inotify-mechanism-and-an-example/) .

Comment: can you please provide me kind of example so i can get more clear how to do this kind of code @Ahamad Anees

Comment: I have updated the link in the answer. It will show you a good example. :-)

Comment: not working it is notify me when new folder is created in device there is anyway for file ?? if new file is created in device then it will notify me have you any idea ?

Comment: Monitor the directory you want to. then "FileObserver.MODIFY" means some data is written into a file inside the directory you are monitoring. Note that if a FileObserver is attached to a folder, then only the files and sub-folders inside it are monitored, but its sub sub-folders and files are not.

Comment: i tried one by one all parameter FileObserver.MODIFY also but not working still notify me when any operation done in directory not done in any file

Comment: Are you sure the file is not inside a sub-directory of the monitoring directory?

Comment: Yes i have given root path so fileobserver observe in device so in device anywhere you are create directory then instantly notify me same task i want for file

Comment: No it will monitor only inside the directory. For example if you give the root path, it will check files only in the root directory. If you want to monitor a sub-directory say, images, you need to add new FileObserver .